# How to get pixel values for comparison

Tags: python-3.x, image

I am trying to get the values of pixels that changed from subsequent images. Suppose if my image1 is 7 and image2 is 9, I am trying to subtract image1 - image2 to get the difference between the two images. However, I would like to know which pixel values changed after taking a difference. I would like to capture all the pixels that changed after subtracting images/frames. Could you please let me know what is the best way to approach this problem? Thanks

```
x_test0 = x_test[18]  
plt.imshow(x_test0, cmap = 'Greys')
plt.show()
x_test1 = x_test[19] 
plt.imshow(x_test1, cmap = 'Greys')
plt.show()
delta_xtest = x_test1 - x_test0
plt.imshow(delta_xtest, cmap = 'Greys')
plt.show()
```

[image: Difference of two images]

Comment: x_test0 and x_test1 are your original arrays. Their difference is the difference between the images.

Comment: That's correct. I want to capture or get all the values that change. in Diagram 3 the changed values are shown. how can I get those values? is there a method which gives the values that changed?

Comment: Just subtract the two arrays and find out which values are != 0.